# What triggers this TypeError? How can I fix it?

Tags: python, instapy

I am trying to code an Instagram Bot that gains me followers using the 'InstaPy' library and I encounterd a TypeError that I can't quite figure out.

My code:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username = "username", password ="password")
session.login()

session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled = True, max_followers = 100)

session.set_do_follow(True, precentage=100)
session.like_by_tags(["x", "y", "z"])
session.set_dont_like(["q"])

session.end()
```

Output:

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firefox_profile'
```

Comment: Please, take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)